# Return top 20% highest value in a column into 1 and make the rest of the numbers 0

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, data-cleaning

Return top 20% highest value in a column into 1 and make the rest of the numbers  0

DF

```
dat1 = data.frame(a = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), b = c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10), c = c(0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16), d = c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.5,0.9), ID=c("Albert", "Bia", "Carla", "Duda", "Elisa"))
```

DESIRED DF

```
dat1 = data.frame(a = c(0,0,0,0,1), b = c(0,0,0,1,0), c = c(0,0,0,0,1), d = c(0,0,0,0,1), ID=c("Albert", "Bia", "Carla", "Duda", "Elisa"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

dat1 %>% mutate(across(a:d, ~as.integer(. > quantile(., 0.8))))

#  a b c d     ID
#1 0 0 0 0 Albert
#2 0 0 0 0    Bia
#3 0 0 0 0  Carla
#4 0 1 0 0   Duda
#5 1 0 1 1  Elisa
```

Answer (score 2):

use `aplly` with `quantile`

```
dat1[,1:4] <- apply(dat1[,1:4], 2, function(x) ifelse(x>=quantile(x, probs = c(0.8, 1))[2],1,0))
```

```
output:
> dat1
  a b c d     ID
1 0 0 0 0 Albert
2 0 0 0 0    Bia
3 0 0 0 0  Carla
4 0 1 0 0   Duda
5 1 0 1 1  Elisa
```

Comment: You can shorten it: `apply(dat1[,1:4], 2, function(x) ifelse(x>=quantile(x, 0.8),1,0))`

Comment: Thanks! May you explain why the number "2"?

Comment: couse `probs = c(0.8, 1)` gives you 2 quantiles. you want use second.

Comment: @Fernanda If you meant the "2" in apply: it stands for the second dimension, here the columns. If you use "1" instead, you would apply the function to the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `colQuantiles`

```
library(matrixStats)
dat1[1:4] <- +(dat1[1:4] >colQuantiles(as.matrix(dat1[1:4])))
```